# Disable a button with comparison condition

Tags: html, angular

I want to disable a button when a condition evaluates to true.

I've tried this way but it doesn't work:

```
<button type="text" disabled="{{candidature.statusCandidature.libelle == 'En cours' }}" >edit </button>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For `angular2+`

```
<button type="text" [attr.disabled]="candidature.statusCandidature.libelle == 'En cours' ? true : null" >edit </button>
```

For `angular1+`

```
<button type="text" ng-disabled="candidature.statusCandidature.libelle == 'En cours'" >edit </button>
```

[Here is a **DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ercxv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Ps:**

For anchor tag disabled property `doesnot` exist,

you need to do,

```
<a [attr.href]="candidature.statusCandidature.libelle == 'En cours' ? null : '#'"
     [class.disabled]="candidature.statusCandidature.libelle == 'En cours'" >edit </a>
```

**css:**

```
a.disabled {
    color: gray;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: @trichetriche, I just copied and forgot to remove `interpolation`. I removed that.

Comment: I'm still keeping my downvote because the syntax isn't a issue, interpolation in attributes work.

Comment: but where is two way binding?

Comment: thats what I was saying, interpolation, I just forgot to remove from my code, when I copied that and corrected it as soon as you said

Comment: And as I told you, interpolation isn't the issue, it works in attributes, so his syntax is supposed to work, [as you can see here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nlsrqd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @trichetriche, I updated my answer, now it works fine

Comment: Still not, you even made it worse. Disabled is supposed to accept a boolean. Be glad null is a falsy value !

Comment: please check the `demo` before getting to a `conclusion`

Comment: I didn't say it's not working, I said you are making it worse. You are using a ternary (to return a boolean) on a condition (which returns a boolean), and you replace the false expected as false with null. That's very bad practice and unclean code.

Comment: yes, because `attr.disabled` needs the falsy value as `null`, and if we remove terniary, it wont work

Comment: Oh **[you sure about that mate ?](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ub7eu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)** And by the way, a falsy value returns `false`, which is a boolean value. You're basically making the same thing thrice.

Comment: thank you if i want to do it with a lick <a> it not work

Comment: @user3529601, I updated my answer and [demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ercxv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) please check

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you

```
<button type="submit" id="test" name="test" [disabled]="!(candidature.statusCandidature.libelle == 'En cours')" >edit </button>
```

Comment: you can also use type text

Comment: You inverted the condition. That's not what he asked, and besides, you have the `!==` operator for that.

Comment: @bhaumik answer is right . Also you can make function for logic of comparison and return boolean.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<button type="text" [disabled]="candidature.statusCandidature.libelle == 'En cours'" >edit</button>
```

Hope this help you!!!

Comment: @bugs **[you sure about that dude ?](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nlsrqd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**, as for Sanoj, I explained, this isn't the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You must bind the disabled attribute like this:

```
<button type="text" [disabled]="candidature.statusCandidature.libelle == 'En cours'" >edit </button>
```